# git - updating working files on the remote server

Tags: git, deployment

I have a remote development server and every time when I do a code change on my local machine I need to make sure the code I've changed works properly on the dev (remote server).Below is the setup I have so far:

1. On the `remote server` I have:

   A git repository created on a folder called `dev` with a bunch of files (I used `git init`  and than `git add .` - to add all those files to the repository).

   Then from that repository I created a branch called `master-copy`.
2. On my `local machine` I created a clone from the remote server's `master-copy` branch. Now every time when I make changes on my clonen copy I do a push to the `master-copy` branch on the remote server.

Is there a way to update the files located on `dev` folder (on the remote server) when I do I push from my `local machine` cloned copy to the `master-copy` branch (on the remote server)?

Comment: I ended up using this: http://joemaller.com/990/a-web-focused-git-workflow/ and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look at [git-receive-pack](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-receive-pack) for information on installing *hooks* which are triggered when you push to a repository.

See [Git Book](http://book.git-scm.com/5_git_hooks.html) for some examples of scripts which can checkout for you after pushing.

Comment: I think fabric might do a better job for what I'm looking for. Here one example I found: http://yuji.wordpress.com/2011/04/09/django-python-fabric-deployment-script-and-example/